# Make this loop faster in R

Tags: performance, r, loops, text-mining

How can I speed up the following (noob) code:

```
#"mymatrix" is the matrix of word counts (docs X terms) 
#"tfidfmatrix" is the transformed matrix
tfidfmatrix = Matrix(mymatrix, nrow=num_of_docs, ncol=num_of_words, sparse=T)

#Apply a transformation on each row of the matrix
for(i in 1:dim(mymatrix)[[1]]){
  r = mymatrix[i,]
  s = sapply(r, function(x) ifelse(x==0, 0, (1+log(x))*log((1+ndocs)/(1+x)) ) )
  tfmat[i,] = s/sqrt(sum(s^2))
}
return (tfidfmatrix)
```

Problem is that the matrices I am working on are fairly large (~40kX100k), and this code is very slow.

The reason I am not using "apply" (instead of using a for loop and sapply) is that apply is going to give me the transpose of the matrix I want - I want num_of_docs X num_of_words, but apply will give me the transpose. I will then have to spend more time computing the transpose and re-allocating it.

Any thoughts on making this faster?

Thanks much.

Edit : I have found that the suggestions below greatly speed up my code (besides making me feel stupid). Any suggestions on where I can learn to write "optimized" R code from?

Edit 2: OK, so something is not right. Once I do `s.vec[!is.finite(s.vec)] <- 0` every element of s.vec is being set to 0. Just to re-iterate my original matrix is a sparse matrix containing integers. This is due to some quirk of the `Matrix` package I am using. When I do `s.vec[which(s.vec==-Inf)] <- 0` things work as expected. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know r, but have you tried moving `dim(mymatrix)` outside the loop? (can you?)

Comment: They probably could but it wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: I believe I found this in the R FAQ some time ago.  http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf.  It is a brilliant and readable guide to vectorizing.

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment,

```
#Slightly larger example data
mymatrix <- matrix(runif(10000),nrow=10)
mymatrix[sample(10000,100)] <- 0
tfmat <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=1000)
ndocs <- 1

justin <- function(){
    s.vec <- ifelse(mymatrix==0, 0, (1 + log(mymatrix)) * log((1 + ndocs)/(1 + mymatrix)))
    tfmat.vec <- s.vec/sqrt(rowSums(s.vec^2))
}

joran <- function(){
    s.vec <- (1 + log(mymatrix)) * log((1 + ndocs)/(1 + mymatrix))
    s.vec[!is.finite(s.vec)] <- 0
    tfmat.vec <- s.vec/sqrt(rowSums(s.vec^2))
}

require(rbenchmark)    
benchmark(justin(),joran(),replications = 1000)

  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2  joran()         1000   0.940  1.00000     0.842    0.105          0         0
1 justin()         1000   2.786  2.96383     2.617    0.187          0         0
```

So it's around 3x faster or so.

Comment: @joran : It never ceases to amaze me what I find on this site. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

not sure what `ndocs` is, but `ifelse` is already vectorized, so you should be able to use the `ifelse` statement without walking through the matrix row by row and `sapply` along the row.  The same can be said for the final calc.

However, you haven't given a complete example to replicate...

```
mymatrix <- matrix(runif(100),nrow=10)
tfmat <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10)
ndocs <- 1

s.vec <- ifelse(mymatrix==0, 0, 1 + log(mymatrix)) * log((1 + ndocs)/(1 + mymatrix))

for(i in 1:dim(mymatrix)[[1]]){
  r = mymatrix[i,]
  s = sapply(r, function(x) ifelse(x==0, 0, (1+log(x))*log((1+ndocs)/(1+x)) ) )
  tfmat[i,] <- s
}

all.equal(s.vec, tfmat)
```

so the only piece missing is the `rowSums` in your final calc.

```
tfmat.vec <- s.vec/sqrt(rowSums(s.vec^2))

for(i in 1:dim(mymatrix)[[1]]){
  r = mymatrix[i,]
  s = sapply(r, function(x) ifelse(x==0, 0, (1+log(x))*log((1+ndocs)/(1+x)) ) )
  tfmat[i,] = s/sqrt(sum(s^2))
}

all.equal(tfmat, tfmat.vec)
```

Comment: I'd bet (a small amount) that ditching `ifelse` entirely, and replacing the `-Inf` values by subsetting with `is.finite` will be even faster.

Comment: @joran I keep hearing that, but haven't tested it myself.  Good point though.  Letting the logs return -Inf and changing them after might be the way to go.

Comment: @justin :Great suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Actually when I run this (on my sparse matrix object), I get the error  `Error in storage.mode(test) <- "logical" : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector` at the point where I try to use ifelse.

Comment: @user721975 You should probably ask that as a separate question with a [small reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that replicates your error.  Since we don't have your data, I made some up and it works great.

Comment: @justin : I think I probably will. BTW, can you explain how `tfmat.vec <- s.vec/sqrt(rowSums(s.vec^2))` is working? I just don't get how each element gets divided by the row sum of the row it is in.